# Uploading data using VBA ADO Transaction

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I'm having a problem while uploading some data from an Excel file (VBA) to Access backend. 
I'm trying to upload 2 records in one transaction. It's done using a loop.

Relevant part of the code:

```vb
cnn.BeginTrans        
'(some test data)
SomeNumber = 2
NewText = "new text"

For i = 0 To 1
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command        
    '(increase [counter] field in database)
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = cnn
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = "UPDATE [tbltest] " & _
        "SET [counter] = [counter] + 1 " & _
        "WHERE [counter]  > ?"
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamInput, , SomeNumber)
        .Execute
    End With

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    '(insert new row in gap)
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = cnn
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO [tbltest] ([counter], [txtfield]) " & _
        "VALUES (?, ?)"
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamInput, , SomeNumber + 1)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, NewText & i)
        .Execute
    End With
Next i
cnn.CommitTrans
```

`tblTest` at beginning:

```
Counter,  txtfield
1      ,  Sometext1 
2      ,  Sometext2 
3      ,  Sometext3 
4      ,  Sometext4
```

Expected output:

```
Counter,  txtfield
1      ,  Sometext1 
2      ,  Sometext2 
5      ,  Sometext3 
6      ,  Sometext4 
3      ,  Sometext1 
4      ,  Sometext0
```

But what I get is

```
Counter,  txtfield
1      ,  Sometext1 
2      ,  Sometext2 
5      ,  Sometext3 
6      ,  Sometext4 
3      ,  Sometext1 
3      ,  Sometext0
```

So, it looks like `counter` inserted in the first loop isn't updated in second.
I've tested same code using SQL Server as backend and it works as intended.
But for some reason it's working different with Access backend.
Am I missing something or it can't be done this way using Access as backend?

Comment: SomeNumber is always 2

Comment: I don't see how that could work with any back end when you don't increment `somenumber` inside the loop so you're always inserting 3 as the new `counter` value.

Comment: Yes but it should be incremented by `UPDATE` in next loop (when i = 1)

Comment: Is the SQL definately getting passed?  `cnn.CommitTrans`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Yes. 2 new rows are uploaded, all rows with `[counter]` > 2 gets incremented by 2. Problem is only with rows inserted within this transaction. It looks like row inserted in fist run of loop isn't updated in second run. So both end up with 3 in `[counter]` field

Comment: Have you used any break points to check your tables after each insert?

Comment: Also, have you tried your begin and commit's inside the loop?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Thank you. I've found it. Looks like all was about to move `Set cmd = New ADODB.Command`from outside to  inside `For` loop before `Update` command.